# How to convert an array of string integers to an array of integers? Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer, data-manipulation

I have an array:

```
all_ages = ["11", "9", "10", "8", "9"]
```

and I want to convert it to an array of integers to hopefully make it easier to add them all together.
Any help greatly appreciated, looking for level one solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
all_ages = ["11", "9", "10", "8", "9"]
```

Code

```
p all_ages.map(&:to_i).sum
```

Or

```
p all_ages.map { |x| x.to_i }.sum
```

Output

```
47
```

Comment: You legend. You have no idea how long I've spent on this. Thank you!

Comment: how else could p all_ages.map(&:to_i).sum be written out?

Comment: Okay, I have updated. could you please check out that?

Comment: `all_pages.sum(&:to_i)`

Comment: I find the ```array.map {block}``` approach to be advantageous in that it also allows an easy way to replace ```x.to_i``` with ```Integer(x)``` if desired.

Comment: @MichaelB: You mean like `array.sum(&method(:Integer))`?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag:  Yes!  I was unaware of that method.  Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: @MichaelB: I suspect you are one of the many unfortunate Rubyists who have been taught to blindly accept `&:` as black magic instead of being "properly" taught that `&` in an argument list is a sigil very much like `*`, where `*` in an argument list "unpacks" an array into separate arguments (if necessary converting to an array first using `to_ary`) and `&` "unpacks" a `Proc` into a block (if necessary converting to a `Proc` first using `to_proc`). Once you understand that, constructs such as `enum.map(&2.method(:+))` for incrementing each member of an enumerable by `2` become natural.

Answer (score 7):

[`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) can be called with a block telling Ruby how to sum the elements of the array, in this case, to call [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) on element first.

```
all_ages = ["11", "9", "10", "8", "9"]
all_ages.sum(&:to_i)
#=> 47
```